# HTML5 Video Autoplay Loop - Unwanted small delay

Tags: html, loops, video, delay, autoplay

I have a question about looping MP4's. I have some small MP4 files that have to keep looping (which works great with "autoplay loop". However, after each play, there seems to be a very short delay before it plays again. Is there a way to avoid this? My code is as follows:

```
<div align="center">
<video autoplay loop class="img-responsive">
<source src="vid/01.mp4" type="video/mp4">
<source src="vid/01.webm" type="video/webm">
</video>
</div>
```

Comment: there's usually a small delay while autoplay resets the playhead, especially if the video is long enough that it's not caching. When you encoded the video did you select faststart (or similar) to make sure the MOOV atom was relocated from the default (end) to the start of the file

Answer (score 0):

With poster attitude you can show a thumbnail before it starts.

```
<video controls poster="/images/w3html5.gif">
  <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```